# Creating E/R Diagrams with Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I am looking for a way to draw E/R Diagrams with Visio. From what I've seen, they seem to look like this

[image]

when instead I want something like this:
[image]

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is look for standard flow chart shapes, not Entity Relationship shapes  - this is easily achieved in Visio.

Either create a new document and choose Flowchart, or load the Flow Chart shapes.

Answer (score 4):

The diagram shown is **not** a flowchart. It is an entity-relationship diagram using Chen's notation. As far as I know, recent versions of Visio do not include Chen ERD stencils, only crowsfoot. You can download a basic Chen ERD stencil set from  the [Visio Cafe](http://www.visiocafe.com/various.htm).